# JavaScript(node.js) - async await does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have some problems using async/await. If i call `getAccountDetails` i only get `undefined` and afterwards i get the log

> `getOpengraphResponse` is ok

But i use async/await. And request is `request-promise-native`. At position one should be the log

> `getOpengraphResponse` is ok

and then the property `details` should be displayed. Where is my mistake?

```
const https = require('https');
const request = require('request-promise-native');
let openGraphBaseURL = "https://graph.facebook.com//v3.1/";


class Account{
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;

    }
}

class InstagramAccount extends Account{
   async getAccountDetails(EdgeID, token){
        this.EdgeID = EdgeID;
        this.token = "&access_token=" + token;
        this.command = this.EdgeID+"?fields=name,username,website,biography,followers_count,follows_count,media_count,profile_picture_url"+this.token;
        this.details =  await this.getOpengraphResponse(this.command);
        console.log(this.details);
    }


    getOpengraphResponse(command){

      request.get({
        url: openGraphBaseURL+command,
        json: true,
        headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
      }, (err, res, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error: ', err);
        }else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
          console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
        } else {

          console.log('getOpengraphResponse is ok');
          return data;
              }

      });
    }
}
```

Comment: `getAccountDetails` doesn't return anything, so does `getOpengraphResponse`

Comment: You aren't using Async/Await. You are using promises and they aren't fully implemented.

Comment: "*`request` is 'request-promise-native'.*" - then why are you passing a callback to it when you say that it uses promises?

Comment: @AdamH What do you mean by "*They aren't fully implemented*"?

Comment: @Bergi Meaning that there is no implementation for .then, .error and nothing is being done with the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

async/await can implemented with promises. i.e

```
var function_name = function(){
    // Create a instance of promise and return it.
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){ 
         // this part enclose some long processing tasks
         //if reject() or resolve()
         //else reject() or resolve() 
    });
}


//function which contains await must started with async
async function(){ 
     // you need to enclose the await in try/catch if you have reject statement  
     try{
         await function_name(); // resolve() is handled here.
         console.log('this will execute only after resolve statement execution');         
     }catch(err){
          // reject() is handled here.         
           console.log('this will execute only after reject statement execution'); 
     }
}
```

You can also use then/catch instead of try/catch.

Comment: Thank you. With a new Promise Object it works. But i thought 'request-promise-native' returns an own Promise.

Comment: sorry for my mistake. but the whole idea is about promise

Answer (score 1):

You can only (usefully) `await` a promise.

`getOpengraphResponse` doesn't return a promise. It has no return statement at all, so it returns `undefined`.

You'll need to treat the return value of `request.get` as a promise. Don't pass it a callback. Do use `then` or `await`.

Return either the value you want (if you `await` inside `getOpengraphResponse`) or the return value of `request.get`.

Comment: You can `await` something that returns `undefined` but don't expect it to do anything useful.

Comment: (`request-promise-native` already returns a promise, there's no need to wrap it, one just has to use it correctly)